# Issue with partial refresh triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jsf, xpages

I have a dojo button bar which is bound to a csjs function. This function does a partialrefreshget() on a datable control. The datatable control contains a view as its datasource.

In the this.keys property I have defined some logic to see if the partialrefresh was triggered by checking for the context.getSubmittedValue(). While experimenting with this technique I noticed that the following code is triggered twice.

```
    <xp:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var vec = new java.util.Vector()
vec.add("category");


if(context.getSubmittedValue()!=null){
    var x = context.getSubmittedValue().trim();

    print("--")
}

return vec;}]]></xp:this.keys>
```

the print statement is printed twice to the console and the logic is therefore triggered twice. Can someone explain to me why this happens and what I can do about it? Should i check for submittedvalues somewhere else or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of testing i gave up calling my own partialrefreshget method.the extlib dojo toolbar contains a onclick event which is triggerd when on a node the submitvalue is set. In this onclik event i added code like

```
Var v = context.getsubmittedvaleu();

If("action".equals(v)){
  // do stuff that changes the dataset.. 
}
```

The event handler is set to partial refresh a datatable wich receives the new data. This is a much cleaner implementation than checking the submittedvalue in the datasource ( as stated by (jeremy hodge).

This way the datasource is only refreshed once.

---

As a sidenote i would like add that it would be nice to add such an event directly to the treenode(s) as I would do in standard java swing /awt dev by adding a controllistener to a button.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you implement a phase listener to print out each phase step, you'll see that this.keys is evaluated twice during the LifeCycle. Probably once during Render Response, and the other during Restore View or something. I would avoid putting application logic within property calculations as it can be triggered at times you would not think it should be unless you are very in tuned with the application lifecycle.

Comment: I think i have to come up with a different solution like triggering a serverside event which does the calculation and when done refresh the datatable.

Answer (score 1):

I actually see the submit two or three times on some controls. I have heard that it is an anomalie in the JSP engine that has not been resolved.

What I do is write the vec to a request scope variable after it is computed. then add logic before it is computed to fetch the request scope variable and if it exisits, return it instead of recomputing the value.